# First vagrant up works but then ruby error after halt/up

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I have installed ruby 2.1.6, vagrant 1.7.2 abd virtual box 4.3.28.

The first `vagrant up` works fine and box is downloaded and server works, but when I run `halt` and then try another `vagrant up` I get the ruby error message below

```
C:/Users/Mike/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/childprocess-0.5.6/lib/childprocess/windows/lib.rb:308: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]

// lots of output listing ruby files

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

The total output is lengthy so I had to upload it separately [**here**](http://textuploader.com/bjt8):

I have tried uninstalling everything and re-installing but the same thing always happens.  Can anyone make sense of this error message for me and give me some advice for fixing it?

The vagrant project is running on my desktop machine fine, this issue is just happening with my laptop.

Comment: I got the same problem today too, seams like it is global issue with Vagrant that accures today, here is bug report. https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11314

Comment: Did you changed VAGRANT_HOME directory or using the default one?  try to change, it works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the same issue since yesterday and I was able to find a workaround through this commands

```
> vagrant plugin install ffi
> vagrant plugin uninstall ffi && vagrant plugin install ffi --plugin-version 1.9.8
```

After that, you should be able to do **vagrant up** without any problem. 
The cause was the latest ffi gem released the other day (I think this only affects windows user), so for someone who just installed or updated vagrant, we need to downgrade the ffi to 1.9.8 for now.

Source: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5869

Comment: It's happening for me with hostsupdater plugin but uninstalling doesn't fix it I have to delete the vagrant.d folder. Is there a way I can see the previous versions available for this plugin and install an older one?

Comment: @Guerrilla, does **vagrant up** works fine for you? Also, are you getting an error message when you try **vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater**?

Comment: If I delete vagrant.d folder vagrant up works fine.  If I install hostupdater there is no error on install.  The error comes when I try to vagrant up.  I can uninstall plugin without error but that doesnt fix it.  I have to delete vagrant.d folder again before it will let me run vagrant up again.,

Comment: You were right.  I didn't realise FFI was installed as it does not appear on `vagrant plugin list` but looking in gem folder it is there.  uninstalling and installing previous version works and now its working again.  Thank you very much, you really helped me out!

Comment: I ran into this issue with chef's kitchen create command and this solution worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue today (It was working last friday). After reinstall/uninstall/restart countless time I am able to solved this issue by doing the following:

1. Go to the .vagrant.d\ folder
2. Delete both plugins.json and the entire gems
3. My existing Vagrantfile had a code to install plugin if not exist. I had to remove it too.

This basically removed all plugins to make it work. I only used vagrant-cachier so not a big deal for me.

Comment: I really need the hostupdater plugin.  is there any way to get plugins working again?  What stopped them working?